# How to use constants defined in one file in another in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-module

Well I have seen couple of questions in StackOverFlow related to this but couldn't find proper answer.

Say in my app.js file I have defined a constants object which basically has controllers names. As I use "ui-router" I want to attach Controllers to views on state change.

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);


app.constant('CONTROLLER', {
    ONE: 'ControllerOne',
    TWO: 'ControllerTwo'
});
```

Now I want to use those constants to define Controller names in other file, say controller.js. Illustrating couple of ways which I tried but dint work for me.

controller.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['CONTROLLER']);

app.controller(CONTROLLER.ONE, ['$scope', 'myFactory', function ($scope, myFactory) {
    $scope.result = myFactory.someAPI();
}]);
```

`ERROR -> Uncaught ReferenceError: CONTROLLER is not defined`

Even I tried injecting that constant module in Controller which gave same error.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['CONTROLLER']);

app.controller(CONTROLLER.ONE, ['$scope', 'myFactory', 'CONTROLLER', function ($scope, myFactory, CONTROLLER) {
    $scope.result = myFactory.someAPI();
}]);
```

I know that second way is wrong. As I define controller names in my main app.js file and use those constants to attach controllers to views during state change. 
I want reuse those constants to define controllers names too.

I may be doing something wrong. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows that you have correctly injected the CONTROLLER constant into the controller constructor function.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['CONTROLLER']);

app.controller(CONTROLLER.ONE, ['$scope', 'myFactory', 'CONTROLLER', function ($scope, myFactory, CONTROLLER) {
    // use constant here
}]);
```

That being said you can only access the constant except from within the controller function itself. The names of controllers, services, factories etc must be accessible strings, which is not the case until the constant has been injected.

You could use a plain old JavaScript object outside angular to define the names.

```
var CONTROLLER = {
    ONE: 'ControllerOne',
    TWO: 'ControllerTwo'
});
```

I can only guess that you are trying to do this because the controller or directive you are writing will be referenced/used at multiple points throughout your html.

Comment: Thanks Yeager, for now that looks fine. Am a Java developer n new to JS world - bit worried of defining constants in plain old JS way as i have heard a lot about Global namespace getting polluted.

Comment: @APD "You could use a plain old JavaScript object outside angular to define the names." How do I do that? I have tried "import { CONTROLLER  } from "./path/to/your/file"" but I get till following error: error: >> error: couldn't process source due to parse error >> 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'